# Spring RestTemplate Connection Timeout is not working

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, httpconnection

I am trying to configure time out when external web service call. I am calling external web service by Spring Rest Template in my service.

For connection timeout testing purpose, the external web service is stopped and application server is down.

I have configured 10 seconds for timeout, but unfortunately i get connection refused exception after a second.

```
try {   
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ((org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)
        restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(1000*10);

    ((org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)
        restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(1000*10);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(reqJSON, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(wsURI, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    String premiumRespJSONStr = response.getBody();
}
```

Please correct my understanding if any.

Comment: are you able to connect without configuring timeout?

Comment: @ Vaibs, No. for testing purpose i did not start external web service. Specified time out is not working.

Comment: Just tested with your code in my environment. Its working fine.Your service should up to test this. To achieve this ,my suggestion is just minimise the connection timeout value . change to 10ms.

Comment: @ Vaibs, when external service is up, setReadTimeout is working. when external service is down, setConnectTimeout is not working. that is, getting exception after a second it is not waiting for 10 second which i configure.

Comment: @ Vaibs, even when i try 10 or 5 ms it is not working. i got successful response from external server.

Comment: If your service is down why rest templte poll for 10 sec.It will directly throw some exception/error

Comment: @ Vaibs, no i tried with server up with 10 and 5 ms - not working. i tried with server down with 5 sec and 10 sec thrown exception within 1 sec.

Comment: @Easy2DownVoteHard2Ans There are two scenarios: 1) the remote server is up but it took longer than `connectTimeout` to get a connection and 2) the server is down and therefore unreachable. For the former the `connectTimeout` should work, for latter it wouldn't make sense because your network client already knows is unreachable and it wouldn't make sense to make you wait up to `comnectTimeout` to tell you so.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo. Thank you for your comment. i have tested with 10.255.255.1 and conncection timeout is working as expected,

Answer (score 47):

The following is related to `connectTimeout` setting.

**Case - unknown host**

If you have a host that is not reachable (eg: `http://blablablabla/v1/timeout`) then you will receive `UnknownHostException` as soon as possible. `AbstractPlainSocketImpl :: connect() :: !addr.isUnresolved() :: throw UnknownHostException` without any timeout. The host is resolved using `InetAddress.getByName(<host_name>)`.

**Case - unknown port**

If you have a host that is reachable but no connection can be done then you receive `ConnectException` - `Connection refused: connect` as soon as possible. It seems that this happens in a native method `DualStackPlainSocketImpl :: static native void waitForConnect(int fd, int timeout) throws IOException` which is called from `DualStackPlainSocketImpl :: socketConnect()`. The timeout is not respected.

**Proxy?** if a proxy is used things might change. Having a reachable proxy you might get the timeout.

**Related questions** check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026223/java-httpurlconnection-timeout-does-not-work) as is related to the case you are encountering.

**DNS Round-Robin** having the same domain mapped to multiple IP addresses will cause the client to connect to each of the IPs until one is found. Therefore the `connectTimeout()` will add its own penalty for each of the IPs in the list which are not working. Read [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) for more.

**Conclusion** if you want to obtain the `connectTimeout` then you might need to implement your own retry logic or use a proxy.

**Testing `connectTimeout`** you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100841/artificially-create-a-connection-timeout-error) of various ways of having an endpoint that prevents a socket connection from completing thus obtaining a timeout. Choosing a solution, you can create an integration test in spring-boot which validates your implementation. This can be similar to the next test used for testing the `readTimeout`, just that for this case the URL can be changed into one that prevents a socket connection.

**Testing `readTimeout`**

In order to test the `readTimeout` there need to be a connection first, therefore the service needs to be up. Then an endpoint can be provided that, for each request, returns a response with a large delay.

The following can be done in spring-boot in order to create an integration test:

**1. Create the test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = { RestTemplateTimeoutConfig.class, RestTemplateTimeoutApplication.class }
)
public class RestTemplateTimeoutTests {

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations restTemplate;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void resttemplate_when_path_exists_and_the_request_takes_too_long_throws_exception() {
        System.out.format("%s - %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().getId());

        Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() ->
                restTemplate.getForEntity(String.format("http://localhost:%d/v1/timeout", port), String.class));

        assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(ResourceAccessException.class);
        assertThat(throwable).hasCauseInstanceOf(SocketTimeoutException.class);
    }
}
```

**2. Configure RestTemplate**

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateTimeoutConfig {

    private final int TIMEOUT = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(getRequestFactory());
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        factory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**3. Spring Boot app that will be run when the test starts**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1/timeout")
public class RestTemplateTimeoutApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestTemplateTimeoutApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) void getDelayedResponse() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.format("Controller thread = %s - %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    }
}
```

**Alternative ways of configuring the RestTemplate**

**Configure existing RestTemplate**

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateTimeoutConfig {

    private final int TIMEOUT = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);

    // consider that this is the existing RestTemplate
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    // this will change the RestTemplate settings and create another bean
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate newRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory =
                (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();

        factory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Configure a new RestTemplate using RequestConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateTimeoutConfig {

    private final int TIMEOUT = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(getRequestFactoryAdvanced());
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactoryAdvanced() {
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT)
                .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .build();

        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    }
}
```

**Why not mocking** using `MockRestServiceServer` with a `RestTemplate`, replaces the request factory. Therefore any `RestTemplate` settings will be replaced. Therefore using a real app for timeout testing might be the only option here.

**Note:** check also [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) about `RestTemplate` configuration which include also the timeout configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the great, inclusive and detailed answer. This is a very helpful guide for dealing with and testing connection timeout issues with Spring.

Comment: nice answer. is setSocketTimeout (in the last RequestConfig version) equivalent to setReadTimeout (1st version) ?